# Query to find if the rows in which a subset of larger set exists

Tags: mysql, sql

There must be a simple solution to this that I can't find or figure out but its driving me insane

There is a table A

```
id 
1
2
3
```

There is a table B

```
id 
a
b
c
```

There is  many to many relation between them table A_B

```
a_id    b_id
 1       a
 1       c
 1       b
 2       a
 2       c
 3       b
```

I want a query that has an input of a set of B's tuples and figures out which of A's tuples have that as a subset.

For example

```
Input c
Output {1,2}

Input {a,c}
Output {1,2}

Input {a,b}
Output {1}

Input {b}
Output {1,3}
```

The only way I've come up with for doing this is selecting all the rows for each individual tag and performing an intersection on these rows. That seems inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query should do what you want; the number of items in the `in` list must match the argument to `having`:

```
select a_id from table_A_B
where b_id in ('a','c')
group by a_id having count(distinct b_id) = 2
```

The `distinct` is only needed if you allow duplicate rows.

See this [sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce56a/2) with your test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can `inner join` your `A_B` table to itself on the `a_id`, which will provide an intersection of that value between the provided `b_id` values:

```
select c.a_id
from A_B as c
where c.b_id = 'c';

select a.a_id
from A_B as a
  inner join A_B as c
    on c.a_id = a.a_id
where a.b_id = 'a'
  and c.b_id = 'c';

select a.a_id
from A_B as a
  inner join A_B as b
    on b.a_id = a.a_id
where a.b_id = 'a'
  and b.b_id = 'b';

select b.a_id
from A_B as b
where b.b_id = 'b';
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db8c71/3)